# .NET MVC - How to get Controller/View specific data to the Layout level from the Model without using ViewBag/ViewData

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, layout, view, model

**How do I access the View Model from inside a Layout? I can only think to use `ViewBag` and `ViewData`, which seems to contradict the MVC pattern.**

I would like to do this because I don't like the way .NET MVC is designed when it comes to pushing data to layouts and non-layout views.

Once can pass a model to the "content root view" (i.e `Return View(myModel)`), but cannot do the same when it comes to the layout. For the layout, one is forced to use `ViewBag` or `ViewData`.

I like the idea of having a "data tree" that perfectly corresponds to my "view tree", and have each view pick its own values from the data, and pass-on the right node to its child views at the moment of including them. I like that because it avoids key name conflicts that you might encounter when using a single dictionary-like collection like `ViewBag` or `ViewData` for a tree of views unaware of one another.

But that fact that .NET MVC doesn't allow passing models to the layout is forcing the use of two différent methods to do the same thing, i.e using `ViewBag` or `ViewData` for the layout, and a "data tree" model for the "content root view", which doesn't seem right to me.

I would have liked to have a single entry point for pushing data to my views, and that would have been the layout itself, not the "content root view".

So based on that, my idea was to stop using layouts completely and, instead, have a root view that would be used as a layout, which would include a tree of partials views, meaning I would never call `@RenderBody()`, but rather call `Html.Partial()` instead.

However, this is moving away from how .NET MVC is supposed to be used, and I know by experience it can lead to problems when not using a technology how it's supposed to be. So here is my dilemma, I don't know if I should just code it how I want it to be coded and take the risk of encountering problems further down the road, or just use .NET MVC the way I'm supposed to and be stuck with this hybrid way of passing data to my views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be interested to see a specific code example of the problem you're facing, for context, if you have one?

Going on what you've said, you are right to be suspicious that you've been forced into using the `ViewBag` as it's not really something we should be using if we can help it. Obviously it's there and can be a good "get out of jail free card", but sticking to view models is certainly better.

Have you considered defining and using sections in your layout/view? They essentially work like a named version of `RenderBody`.

For example, in your Layout you might have:

```
@RenderSection("SideBar", required: false)
```

This can be accessed from your view, like this:

```
@model your.namespace.viewmodel    

... some view cshtml ...

@section SideBar {
    <h4>Related content for @Model.Name</h4>
    ...
}
```

Check out this [overview of sections](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor), it includes more in depth examples and also how to define default section content on the occasions you don't want to pass anything.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I correctly understand, what you're suggesting me to do is to move the content of the layout (that can possibly contain parameterized markup, like header, side panel, footer, etc) outside of the layout itself, and have it defined within the root (non-layout) view, from which the model is accessible for use in the markup that would otherwise be defined in the layout ? So I would have an empty layout that renders the sections (header, panel, etc), and a regular view that would define the content of my layout ?

Comment: It's quite confusing for me to imagine how your layout is setup and what type of things you require the ViewModel to achieve, it doesn't sound typical/standard? The example in the link I shared uses the idea of a sidebar, so perhaps you have a common part of the sidebar (e.g. recent blog posts from the site), which would go into the main layout and then page/view specific aspects that need your current model can be managed via your section in the view (e.g. blog specific post date & author)

Comment: When considering a "common part of the siderbar", like a recent blog posts section, I would suggest you use `@Html.RenderAction` in your layout, which takes a controller + action (i.e. `@Html.RenderAction("Latest", "Blogs")`. Then, inside your controller you can fetch the latest blogs from the DB. Let's say your current blog id is in the URL, you can access this from the ViewContext and exclude it that way. This then renders to it's own Partial view with a unique view model.

Comment: Finally, inside your `Layout.cshtml` you do not need to declare the ViewModel type (i.e. `@model your.namespace.model`). This would result in the @Model being handled as a `dynamic` type and you can `@Model.DoWhatYouWant`. Don't do this mind you as we prefer strongly typed objects - what would be better is to define an `Interface` or (a "base" class) which all your view models derive from, then declare this in your Layout and you'll be able to access these parts of the view model from the layout, you just need to always populate inside each view.  https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_interface.php